# How to convert a program which uses inheritance to a program that only uses composition?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, composition

I've read that **composition** can be used instead of **inheritance** and all programs using inheritance can be transformed to a program using composition and vice-versa. I've also read that using composition is better than using inheritance.

Even though I've read the facts, I don't understand how and why this is true. I can't even think of an example to demonstrate this.

Could someone please help me clear out my doubts. It would be very much appreciated if you could use an example too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Comment: *"I've also read that using composition is better than using inheritance."* - As a general statement that is not true.  Or at least, a matter of opinion.

Comment: The possibility to convert one approach into the other tells us nothing about the question which one is better in a given situation. So, you have to decide whether an "is-a" relationship suits better than a "has" relationship.

Comment: "I've also read that using composition is better than using inheritance.", with deep hierarchies, searching for the right method at runtime takes time. With composition or aggregation, it is just a matter of getting the method reference from the instance variable

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance is `is` relationship. E.g., teacher is human.

Composition is `has` relationship. E.g., `pizza` has `tomato`.

Inheritance makes tight coupling between your classes such as Child class and Parent class. So making changes can be a reason to make changes in all inherited classes.

Composition is very effective when you want to define what behavior should be used at the compile time and run time. You can create an interface and give realization of this interface at at the compile time and run time.

Inheritance is very good when we reuse methods and we want to override them. However, you can use composition to achieve this goal.

[There is a nice article about Composition over inheritance. It says:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

> Composition over inheritance (or composite reuse principle) in
> object-oriented programming (OOP) is the principle that classes should
> achieve polymorphic behavior and code reuse by their composition (by
> containing instances of other classes that implement the desired
> functionality) rather than inheritance from a base or parent class.

An example of inheritance:

```
public class Human
{
    string Title;
    string Name;
    int Age;
}

public class Teacher : Human
{
    int Salary;
    string Subject;
}
```

An example of composition:

```
public interface IEngine
{
    string Name { get; }
    decimal Volume { get; }
}

public class Engine : IEngine
{
    public string Name => "Foo Engine";
    public decimal Volume => 4;
}


public class Car
{
    private IEngine _engine;

    public Car(IEngine _engine)
    {
        _engine = engine;
    }
}
```

Comment: But now you have two classes which have no common behavior, but with inheritance, you could pass Teacher into places where Human is expected. Shouldn't we implement some IHuman interface on both of these classes to make they comply?

Comment: @ΕГИІИО It was an example and I remade it to make it clearer :)